# Is there a robot in Clone Wars or Rebels that fulfuls the 'salesman' aspect of George Lucas' original vision for C3P0?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels, george-lucas, c-3po

There is [evidence](https://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/ent/c-3po-sleazy-star-wars.html) that [George Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lucas)' original vision for [C3P0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-3PO) was that he was to be a [sleazy salesman](https://www.starwarsforum.co.uk/threads/traces-of-the-%E2%80%9Ccar-salesman%E2%80%9D-c-3po.26392/) type personality.

Later we see that Lucas chose to use [Anthony Daniels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Daniels)' voice (in addition to the body) for C3P0 - and the idea for a 'salesman' personality was thrown out.

We know that in [Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) and [Star Wars Rebels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels), [Dave Filoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Filoni) [sought](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-art-of-star-wars-rebels-interview) to [recapture](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/how-ralph-mcquarries-art-inspired-star-wars-rebels/) many aspects of George Lucas' original vision for Star Wars.

My Question is: **Is there a robot in Clone Wars or Rebels that fulfils the 'salesman' aspect of George Lucas' original vision for C3P0?**